# Login page in flutter that auths user for 3rd party service without redirection

Tags: flutter, webview

I want to create an app that uses some 3rd party api, and I want to make logging in to its service as easy as possible without the user needing to leave my application, but I don't really know what options are suitable or exist at all for this purpose.

I've already heared about webview, but when I tried tu pub add it I've got noticed about it not supporting null safety.

My artificial programming mate mentioned iframe, after which I decided to ask about all this here,, since I don't know how to handle plugins, external code, etc.

To sum up, my question then is what the standard is for this purpose?

Thanks

webview, flutter_html_iframe